# Do you know how to zoom content in WKWebView like it does safari?

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile-safari, wkwebview

I need to add to WKWebView the same functionality as safari has (aA). But I don't find any properties in WKWebView which allow to do the same.

Do you know how safari does this?

Is it possible to reproduce the same in WKWebView?
[image: example of functionality in Safari here]

Comment: Just a thought I don't know if this will work but you could execute javascript code like `document.body.style.zoom = "80%";` to zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this

```
let js = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust='200%'"//dual size
webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
```